# Type error in ternary operator in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm doing a class in c++ to generalize two sparse matrix solvers (SparseLU and Sparse Cholesky). When I try to use the ternary operator it says that the operand types are incompatible, but if I use the If statement, the code compiles.

> Error 2 error: operand types are incompatible ("const Eigen::Solve < Eigen::SimplicialLDLT < Eigen::SparseMatrix < double, 0, int > , 1, Eigen::AMDOrdering < int > > , Eigen::Matrix < double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1 > > " and "const Eigen::Solve < Eigen::SparseLU < Eigen::SparseMatrix < double, 0, int > , Eigen::COLAMDOrdering < int > > , Eigen::Matrix < double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1 > > ")

```
eigen::VectorXd solve(eigen::VectorXd &b) {
    return is_cholesky ? cholesky.solve(b) : lu.solve(b); // ERROR
}
```

X

```
eigen::VectorXd solve(eigen::VectorXd &b) {
    if (is_cholesky) {
        return cholesky.solve(b);
    }
    else {
        return lu.solve(b);
    }
}
```

The whole code:

```
#pragma once  

#ifndef SOLVER_H
#define SOLVER_H

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/SparseLU>
#include <Eigen/SparseCholesky>

#define eigen Eigen

class Solver {
private:
    bool is_cholesky;
    eigen::SimplicialLDLT<eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> cholesky;
    eigen::SparseLU<eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> lu;

public:
    Solver(bool is_choleski) {
        this->is_cholesky = is_choleski;
    }

    eigen::ComputationInfo info() {
        return is_cholesky ? cholesky.info() : lu.info();
    }

    void compute(eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &B) {
        is_cholesky ? cholesky.compute(B) : lu.compute(B);
    }

    eigen::VectorXd solve(eigen::VectorXd &b) {
        return is_cholesky ? cholesky.solve(b) : lu.solve(b); // ERROR HERE
    }
};

#endif // SOLVER_H
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for the type of a `a ? b : c` expression require that it is either the type of the `b` expression or the type of the `c` expression.

Here `cholesky.solve(b)` has a type different to `lu.solve(b)` and neither has an implicit conversion to the other. That the resulting expression will need a conversion to `eigen::VectorXd` is ignored. Thus the "operand types are incompatible" error.

```
return is_cholesky ? cholesky.solve(b) : lu.solve(b); // ERROR
```

Here each expression directly has to have a conversion to `eigen::VectorXd`, which exists.

```
if (is_cholesky) {
    return cholesky.solve(b);
}
else {
    return lu.solve(b);
}
```

You can force the type of the `?:` expression to `eigen::VectorXd` by mentioning it explicitly, e.g.

```
return is_cholesky ? eigen::VectorXd{ cholesky.solve(b) } : lu.solve(b);
```

Comment: Thanks Caleth! Is there any difference between `eigen::VectorXd{cholesky.solve(b)}` and `(eigen::VectorXd) cholesky.solve(b)` ?

Comment: @RaphaelSampaio To the compiler: no. To a programmer: the former *can't* mean reinterpret_cast, nor const_cast, the latter *can*